# Mistake on resume for grad school application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application

So, I noticed a small typo in my resume two weeks after submitting it. In my professional summary, I accidentally put "counselling" instead of "counseling". Are small typos overlooked or detrimental? I didn't notice anything else but I also don't want to keep looking and then cause my anxiety to increase more.

I ended up finding two typos. The end bullet said "task included" instead of "tasks included". Ugh. :(

Comment: Are you using American English or British English throughout your resume?

Comment: American. I had my uncle help with my resume so I'm assuming he changed it and it took me a while to notice.

Comment: @Allure, thank you! It just concerns me since some say it's a big deal and others say we're all human and mistakes happen.

Comment: Don't panic. It will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

No, it won't be a problem and might not even be noticed. Relax.

However, applying to only once school is probably suboptimal. Competition can be pretty fierce and most places get high quality applicants. Cast a broader net if you can.

And get a spell checker for the long term. The one here fixes lots of my typos (blush).

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about applying to one more but the problem is I really want to be on campus somewhere and since my husband and I own a house, we can't just up and move so my only other options are online. Online just doesn't seem as appealing to me. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely not a problem! I screen loads of applications and can assure you that a) no one will notice and b) if they do they won't care. If your application is littered with errors that's a different matter, but a typo is fine.

Comment: I just noticed one more at the very bottom where it said "task include" instead of "tasks include". With both of them being on there, will I still have a chance? I honestly read over that bottom part so many times and never caught that either. :( I'm hoping these are things that they won't notice?

Comment: I had to read that comment twice even to spot the typo you were talking about. It really will not matter. The person reading it probably has 100 applications to get through. They are not looking for typos!